# How to implement Quill Emojis in vue2editor?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, laravel-5.6

I tried to add Quill Emojis to editor but I am getting console error as

`Uncaught ReferenceError: Quill is not defined`

I am using Laravel 5.6 and vue js and definately new to vue and its components so I may sound silly to you but for the past 3 days I am searching on the google for the solution and even contacted author of vue2editor on github here is [the link](https://github.com/davidroyer/vue2-editor/issues/143#issue-355947664)

This is what I have tried so far:

**vue2editor.vue**

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <vue-editor v-model="content"></vue-editor>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import { VueEditor, Quill } from 'vue2-editor';
    import Emoji from 'quill-emoji/dist/quill-emoji';
    Quill.register('modules/quill-emoji', Emoji);


    export default {
        name: 'vue2editor',
        components: { VueEditor },
        data() {
            return {
                content: "<h1>Some initial content</h1>",
                editorSettings: {
                    modules: {
                        toolbar: {
                            container: [
                                [{'size': ['small', false, 'large']}],
                                ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'],
                                ['blockquote', 'code-block'],
                                [{ 'header': 1 }, { 'header': 2 }],
                                [{ 'list': 'ordered' }, { 'list': 'bullet' }],
                                [{ 'script': 'sub' }, { 'script': 'super' }],
                                [{ 'indent': '-1' }, { 'indent': '+1' }],
                                [{ 'direction': 'rtl' }],
                                [{ 'header': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, false] }],
                                [{ 'color': [] }, { 'background': [] }],
                                [{ 'font': [] }],
                                [{ 'align': [] }],
                                ['clean'],
                                ['link', 'image', 'video'],
                                ['emoji'],
                            ],
                            handlers: {
                                'emoji': function () {}
                            },
                        },
                        toolbar_emoji: true,
                        short_name_emoji: true,
                        textarea_emoji:true,
                    },
                },
                text: null,
            };
        },
    };
</script>
```

I even tried the method mentioned by one of the user on github for Quill-Emoji, here is the [link](https://github.com/contentco/quill-emoji/issues/26#issue-350294074).

I came here with lots of hopes; if anyone here is to help me out, at least tell me what I am missing will be more than a help for me.

Comment: Is there no one interested in helping me out  ?

Comment: I think this will solve your problem https://github.com/surmon-china/vue-quill-editor/issues/322

Answer (score 0):

```
Quill.register({
'formats/emoji': Emoji.EmojiBlot,
'modules/short_name_emoji': Emoji.ShortNameEmoji,
'modules/toolbar_emoji': Emoji.ToolbarEmoji,
'modules/textarea_emoji': Emoji.TextAreaEmoji}, true);
```

you need register the model, add the up code to you code.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

```
//1) Add plugin to laravel mix

    const mix = require('laravel-mix')
    mix.webpackConfig(webpack => {
        return {
            plugins: [
                new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                    "window.Quill": "quill/dist/quill.js",
                    Quill: "quill/dist/quill.js"
                })
            ]
        };
    });


//2 example vue file


 

<template>
      <div class="mt-1">
        <vue-editor
          ref="editor"
          v-model="content"
          :editor-toolbar="customToolbar"
          :editorOptions="editorSettings"
        />
    

      </div>
    </template>
    <script>
    import { VueEditor, Quill } from "vue2-editor";
    
    import Emoji from "quill-emoji/dist/quill-emoji";
    Quill.register("modules/emoji", Emoji);
    
    export default {
      components: {
        VueEditor,
      },
      props: {
        bubble: Object,
        contentCol: {
          type: String,
        },
      },
      data() {
        return {
          edit: false,
          content: "<b>Content is here</b>",
          customToolbar: [["bold", "italic", "underline"], ["link"], ["emoji"]],
          editorSettings: {
            modules: {
              "emoji-toolbar": true,
              "emoji-textarea": true,
              "emoji-shortname": true,
            },
          },
        };
      },
      beforeDestroy() {},
    
     
    };
    </script>
    
    <style  src="quill-emoji/dist/quill-emoji.css"/>
```